# What is sizeof() variable length array?

Tags: c, sizeof

In a recent post I saw:

```
scanf("%d" , &TASK_NO);
struct task_info tasks[TASK_NO];
printf("total: %d\n", sizeof(tasks)/sizeof(tasks[0]));
```

with a comment: "`sizeof()` is evaluated at compile time, not runtime, so will not give the correct number for total."

In all the history of the C language, `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time and can be given a declared array (a declared array is something like `int a[10];` and `sizeof(a)` gives 10 times the size of an int). With C99 it is possible to provide the size of an array that is an automatic variable in run time. Does this mean that `sizeof` for the declared automatic array `tasks[TASK_NO]` must be evaluated at run time? I.e., has `sizeof` become something that is sometimes evaluated at run time? If not, is it defined as an error to ask `sizeof` for a VLA (so the compiler would give a warning/error message as what you are asking is *known* to not be decidable at compile time)?

Comment: Partly good reasoning (well, the actual behaviour limits somewhat those possibilities). Now why don't you check a manual? :) http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof

Comment: @Karoly-Horvath, thanks for the pointer. Makes sense now: since C99 there are runtime requirements placed on `sizeof`.